# Do Google App Engine app instances restart when updating an app where only static files changed

Tags: google-app-engine

Let’s assume I have an app that has some static files and some code. The static files are described in app.yaml as such. I have uploaded my app for the first time.

If I now just change static files and re-upload my app will GAE restart my instances? If no this is what I expected and all I was wondering. If no, is there a way—apart from using a 3rd party CDN for the static files— to upload static content without restarting running instances?

Comment: Any reason you are particularly worried that instances my or may not restart ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SDK uploader it will update the entire content, both static files and code of the module(s) being uploaded and it will restart the instances matching the default version of the respective module(s).

You could, if you want, just change the version of the module - the existing instances will be left alone, serving requests coming to urls formulated specifically for those versions. But all new requests coming to the default version (the latest uploaded) will be served by the new instance(s).